# Abstract class with no methods

Tags: java, abstract-class

Is there a use case where we would need an abstract class with no methods defined in it? I bumped into creating such an abstract class just for the sake of generics so that users will pass only subtypes of this class. But I want to know if either is valid or there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Try what? I know we can do it.I am asking if there is a use case

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: Because there might be hidden gotchas, which is why he's asking here.

Comment: Sounds like an interface to me....

Comment: @piet.t The OP stated that there were **no method** in it. Not that there were **no *implemented* methods** in it. So an interface does not make more sense anyway, unless it's a marker.

Comment: @Joffrey: ah, got it...

Comment: Not sure why this question is put on hold for the reason "lacking sufficient information to diagnose the problem". The question is very simple and straight forward, what is the use case of having an abstract class with no methods. It does not need more details

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed - it is true that it's brief, yet it has all the information necessary to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having an abstract class with no methods is legal, yet entirely pointless. You use abstract classes to share *implementation*. If a class has no methods, it has no implementation to share.

If you need to share some common variables (I assume that your abstract class has at least some fields, otherwise it is entirely empty) you would be better off with composition and an interface, like this:

```
class CommonData {
    // Some getters and setters for items that you wish to share
}
interface WithCommonData {
    CommonData getCommonData();
}
```

Your classes can put the common data as a member, and implement the interface `WithCommonData`, giving you access to the common data, and letting the classes keep their inheritance structure.

If you need to "mark" a user class, doing it with a "marker interface" (i.e. an interface with no methods) is a lot more flexible, because the users retain an ability to build their own chain of inheritance.

Comment: I don't see why composition is a better fit than inheritance to share variables. Would you care to explain please?

Comment: According to your post update, I take it that IYO it's better because you're free to inherit from something else even with this shared data, right? In that case, IMO it depends on the semantics of the classes. If an inheritance hierarchy makes sense with respect to the real world represented by the classes, I would go with inheritance.

Comment: @Joffrey It is better when you need others to share data in their classes, rather than building your own inheritance hierarchy. When the hierarchy is yours, sharing through inheritance is easier. When the hierarchy is someone elses' (which I think is the case with OP, because he writes "users will pass only subtypes") they may have their own base classes from which they inherit, so it may not be possible to inherit from your class as well.

Comment: I agree with you when you make the distinction between code you control, and code you don't. However, I don't think the OP meant that by "users", I think he meant *the using code*.

Comment: Yes, by users, I mean by using code. But I get the entire point by your discussion. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Creating an abstract class just because other classes should be of that type is not neccessary. This can instead be achieved using interfaces.
Since a class only can extend one class but implement any number of interfaces, using an interface as an instance validator will not limit a solution with respect to inheritance.

Example:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    // No methods, we just want several classes to be identified as of type Vehicle
}


public class Car implements Vehicle {
    // is a vehicle
}

public class Motorcycle implements Vehicle {
    // is a vehicle
}

public class Banana {
    // is not a vehicle
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object o = new Car();
        if(o instanceof Vehicle) {
            // Ok
        }

        Object p = new Banana();
        if(p instanceof Vehicle) {
            // Will never get here
        }
    }
}
```